# Exporting Scaled Down Artwork to PDF for Large Scale Print

Tags: print-production

I've been a graphic designer working mostly in print for the past 15 years and I just realised that the way I have been exporting for Large Scale Print has been wrong this whole time.

Normally if there is something that is a few metres I might create the artwork at say 10 or 50% keeping things like bleed to scale. I make sure images will be at least 150dpi when scaled up so if it's 10% I will make sure the images are 1500dpi.

However most print PDF defaults compress any images over 300dpi down to 300dpi. I only just realised that all those scaled images I've been setting up have been scaled down again.

I've never had a printer come back to me saying there was an issue. For anyone working in print production, would you just run it as is because it's not usually a problem or are there no preflight systems that pick this up?

Comment: If there was a problem, the print operator might pick this up visually when the first copy comes out of the printer, but I doubt if a preflight check of the PDF would take subsequent enlargements into account. It would just see 300dpi images, which are usually acceptable for most print jobs, and not flag them.

Answer (score 1):

I am paranoid :o) so I would use the correct terms in the first place, this is one of those things that will make you a better print production guy.

> most print PDF defaults compress any images over 300dpi down to 300dpi

No, they are not compressed, they are resampled, and this is a checkbox that can be easily deactivated.

> DPI

The unit you should use is PPI, regardless that they are commonly used as the same unit they are not.

> I make sure images will be at least 150dpi

150 PPI as a final resolution is probably too much. 100 PPI is a good resolution that will not be visible on an image at 1 m.

The images you export at 10% at 300PPI have a final resolution of 30 PPI, which is in fact still a decent resolution. It is a small square of less than 1 mm when viewed at a couple of meters is again unnoticeable. As long as the text remain as a vector, this is still a good file.

Regarding your question

> For anyone working in print production, would you just run it as is because it's not usually a problem

I am not in that part of the chain of print production, but in any case, that specific issue is no obstacle to print it as it is. I mentioned it early 30PPI is a good resolution for a few meters print. **There is no way to know** you intended a greater resolution but did not unchecked the resample box.

An example of a warning that should not be allowed to continue without double-checking is, for example, a small black text in RGB colors. That kind of warning should be stoped and called upon.

> are there no preflight systems that pick this up?

Probably you can setup a warning if a file has less PPI on a file than some amount, but 300PPI is a standard good resolution so, there is nothing to warn about.